# Connecting Foreign Key to URL in Django

Tags: django, url, primary-key, slug

I'm creating an online courses website, in which you create a course object and add chapter objects to it. Each chapter has a foreign key to a course object:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False)
    cover = models.ImageField(null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    pack = models.ForeignKey(CoursePack, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 
    tag = models.ForeignKey(CourseGroup, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Course, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("course_detail", kwargs={'pk':self.pk,'slug': self.slug})

    signals.pre_save.connect(instance_pre_save, sender="course.Course")

class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=False)
    text = RichTextUploadingField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Chapter, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("chapter_detail", kwargs={'pk':self.pk,'slug': self.slug,
                                                 "cpk":self.course.pk, "cslug":self.course.slug})
```

my view is like this:

```
def chapter_view(request, pk, slug, cpk, cslug):
    context = {}

    chapter = Chapter.objects.get(pk=pk, slug=slug, cpk=cpk, cslug=cslug)

    context["chapter"] = chapter

    return render(request, "courses/chapter_detail.html", context)
```

And here is the url path:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<cslug>[-\w]+),(?P<cpk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+),(?P<pk>\d+)/$', chapter_view, name='chapter'),
```

And here is the anchor tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'chapter' slug=chapter.slug cslug=chapter.cslug pk=chapter.pk cpk=chapter.cpk %}" >{{ chapter }}</a>
```

I'm getting the error:

> FieldError at /cursos/name-of-the-course,course-pk-integer/name-of-the-chapter,chapter-pk/
>
> Cannot resolve keyword 'cpk' into field. Choices are: course,
>   course_id, id, slug, text, title

Which shows that the URL is found, but I don't get why it doesn't just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `chapter_view` you are trying to access directly the field of course. You must use the course.

```
Chapter.objects.get(pk=pk, slug=slug, course__pack=cpk, course__slug=cslug)
```

Is also confusing use a variable like `cpk` because I don't understand if you refer to a pk field in Course or a pack field in Course.

Answer (score 1):

The `.get()` method accept parameter with its field names or related fields.

In your `Chapter` model, there is no attribute/fields named `cpk` so, Django can't resolve that key into a field name. That's why the exception is raising.

In your case, the parameter, `cpk` and `cslug` are non-field references, so it should replace or rename to some actual attributes. So it should be like this

```
def chapter_view(request, pk, slug, cpk, cslug):
    context = {}

    chapter = Chapter.objects.get(pk=pk, slug=slug, course__pack=cpk, course__slug=cslug)

    context["chapter"] = chapter

    return render(request, "courses/chapter_detail.html", context)
```

Read [this official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/) for more info regarding django orm queries.